# d3.js prevent resizing of svg element

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

i am trying to prevent resize of tooltip when resizing the whole svg, because the tooltip became too small and unreadable. The tooltip itself is a ticket type and its very important to keep its width and height regardless the size of the viewBox. So is there a way to prevent a defined element from resizing while everything else part of the svg is resized ??

```
 const svg = svgEl
      .classed(css.svgContainer, true)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
      .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${height + margin.top + 
       margin.bottom}`)
      // .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      // .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
      .classed(css['svg-content-responsive'], true)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform',
        'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
   
      pointFormat: function (point) {
        return `<div><div>${point?.score}</div><div>${point?.gameClock}${point?.quarter}</div> 
       </div><div>${point?.name}</div>`
      }


      // Adding foreignObject to home the html element
      const fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
        .attr('width', 175)
        .attr('class', 'svg-tooltip')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${xScale(X[i])},${yScale(Y[i])})`)
        .attr('x', tooltipX(O[i].x))
        .attr('y', tooltipY(O[i].y, foHeight))
        .style('pointer-events', 'none')

      const div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
        .datum(O[i])
        .append('div')
        .attr('x', O[i].x)
        .attr('y', O[i].y)
        .style('z-index', '-2')
        .attr('class', css.tooltipEvent)
        .html(d => pointFormat(d))

      // Finding the height of the tooltip element and add it dynamically to the foreignObject
      foHeight = div._groups[0][0].getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: you may try to make the tooltp a div or other external html element

Comment: this is what i am doing, thats why i am using foreignObject, but it is resized as svg resized.

Comment: You are appending a `div` as a `foreignObject` to an `svg`. The usual approach is more is setup `<div>tootltip goes here</div><svg> chart in here </svg>`

Comment: as I've commented above: the div needs to be *external*. Don't put it in a foreign object.

Comment: excuse me but could you be more concrete, if you append div without foreignObject you cant see it in the svg, because div is not svg`s element. The problem which i am trying to solve is that these tooltips are shown once you hover on a path and once you catch an event tooltip is shown. How to connect after that the tooltip and svg if you use your approach ?